# Smart Map - How to search by a field in address?

Tags: search, plugin-smartmap

I have entries using the Smart Map address field. I need to get just the entries that have a combination of city and state (city = "Beverly Hills" AND state = "CA"). I am currently only trying to get simpler search state working and only then will I move to state/city. I can get a "fuzzy" that to my understanding will get everything that has "CA" in any of the fields using:

```
{% set meetings = craft.entries.section('meetings').search('address:' ~ 'CA') %}
```

But I want to understand how to create a more specific search that specifically finds 'CA' in address.state.

When I try:

```
{% set meetings = craft.entries.section('meetings').search('address.state:' ~ 'CA') %}
```

the search returns nothing. No errors either.

Questions:

- How do I search specifically in a field like address.state?
- Extending this question, how do I search address.state AND address.city?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more "filtering" than "searching", but take a look at this...

> [Filtering entries by subfield value](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/filtering-entries-by-subfield-value/)

Set a `filter` parameter when creating your element criteria model...

```
{% set params = {
    filter: {
        city: 'Beverly Hills',
        state: 'CA'
    }
} %}

{% set meetings = craft.entries.address(params) %}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Follow up...If I wanted to filter just by cities and group them so my 10 meetings in Beverly Hills just appears as on listing for Beverly Hills how would I do that with the "set params = " syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You may want to [ask a new question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and go into a bit more detail.

Comment: New question posted here. Hopefully clearer. :)  https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25270/getting-unique-values-from-smartmap-addresses